# Sharing Google Calendar with wife so she can see it on iPhone

Tags: data-synchronization, iphone, google, sharing, calendar

So I have two calendars that I share with my wife. One is normal (which she can see all details for) and the other (my counseling calendar) is for my therapy client schedule. I want her to be able to see when I'm busy but no details, as I put the client's name so I know who I'm going to be counseling at the appointed time. I set the share settings to public but so it wouldn't show details (only free/busy time). And when she logs into her Google calendar on a computer, it shows up correctly, i.e. it only shows the appointments for me as being "busy."

So the main issue is this: I cannot get her iPhone to be able to show my counseling calendar. When she goes to the Google Sync page on her iPhone where you can choose which calendars you want your iPhone to sync with, my counseling calendar will not show up. It will only show up if I give her rights to see details... which is unacceptable because of patient confidentiality, etc.

Has anyone heard of this problem or have any ideas??

Comment: Did you try googling it beforehand? Here is what came up on google: http://email.about.com/od/googlecalendartips/qt/Make_a_Google_Calendar_or_Free_Busy_Information_Public.htm

Comment: It appears those instructions have already been followed; I wonder if this might not be a failure of the iOS Google Calendar client.

Answer (score 2):

The iOs Calendar client doesn't support availability-only calendars, that's why they are not listed on the Google Sync settings page.

Sorry!